# Use Json to Populate Chart with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a JSON file that I would like to populate with a BarChart through `cshtml`.

JSON File:

```
[{
    "Subject": "TEST APP",
    "AppScores": [{
        "Season": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "year": "1",
        "value": "44"
    }, {
        "Season": "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
        "year": "2",
        "value": "29"
    }]
}, {
    "Subject": "TEST APP2",
    "AppScores": [{
        "Season": "CCCCCCCCCCC",
        "year": "3",
        "value": "15"
    }, {
        "Season": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD",
        "year": "4",
        "value": "32"
    }]
}]
```

The code within my `cshtml` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myChart = new JSChart('chartid', 'bar');
    myChart.setDataJSON('data2.json');
    myChart.draw();
</script>
```

My `data2.json` file is located within the same directory as the `cshtml file`.

Can anyone see what I am missing here?

Comment: try use complete address like : "/Views/Home/data2.json"